# show ad after every 3 row in react native, undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item[0].type') in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am able to show ad after every 3 row . with defined data
like this

```
const DATA =[
  {images: [], _id: '614c0cde71cb0e4a6cd8be1c', name: 'Tools & Machineries'},
  {images: [], _id: '614c0cde71cb0e4a6cd8be1d', name: 'Furniture'},
  {images: [], _id: '614c0cde71cb0e4a6cd8be1e', name: 'Safety & Security'},
  {images: [], _id: '614c0cde71cb0e4a6cd8be1f', name: 'Lighting'},
  {images: [], _id: '614c0cde71cb0e4a6cd8be20', name: 'Measuring & Layout'},
  {images: [], _id: '614c0cde71cb0e4a6cd8be21', name: 'Flooring'},
  {images: [], _id: '614c0cde71cb0e4a6cd8be22', name: 'Generators'},
  {images: [], _id: '614c0cde71cb0e4a6cd8be1c', name: 'Tools & Machineries'},
  {images: [], _id: '614c0cde71cb0e4a6cd8be1d', name: 'Furniture'},
  {images: [], _id: '614c0cde71cb0e4a6cd8be1e', name: 'Safety & Security'},
  {images: [], _id: '614c0cde71cb0e4a6cd8be1f', name: 'Lighting'},
  {images: [], _id: '614c0cde71cb0e4a6cd8be20', name: 'Measuring & Layout'},
  {images: [], _id: '614c0cde71cb0e4a6cd8be21', name: 'Flooring'},
  {images: [], _id: '614c0cde71cb0e4a6cd8be22', name: 'Generators'},
]
```

but when I set My API data which same like above then error is coming like this

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item[0].type')
```

I am setting my data like this

```
 const [DataForCategory, setDataForCategory] = useState([]);
form API--
setDataForCategory(response.data);
```

this is my logic

```
const modifyData = (data) => {
    const numColumns = 3;
    const addBannerIndex = 9;

    const arr = [];
    var tmp = [];
    data.forEach((val, index) => {
      if (index % numColumns == 0 && index != 0) {
        arr.push(tmp);
        tmp = [];
      }
      if (index % addBannerIndex == 0 && index != 0) {
        arr.push([{type: 'banner'}]);
        tmp = [];
      }
      tmp.push(val);
    });
    arr.push(tmp);
    return arr;
  };
  const renderItem = (item, index) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(item));
    if (item[0].type == 'banner') {
      return (
        <FlatListSlider
          data={list}
          timer={3000}
          imageKey={'image'}
          local={true}
          width={screenWidth}
          height={100}
          separator={0}
          loop={true}
          autoscroll={true}
          //currentIndexCallback={(index) => console.log('Index', index)}
          onPress={(item) => console.log(JSON.stringify(item))}
          indicatorContainerStyle={{position: 'absolute', bottom: 20}}
          indicatorActiveColor={'#ffffff'}
          indicatorInActiveColor={'#898489'}
          indicatorActiveWidth={25}
          animation
        />
      );
    }

    const columns = item.map((val, index) => {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('SubCategories')}>
          <View key={index} style={styles.container2}>
            {/* <Image
              source={{uri: item.images}}
              style={{width: 70, height: 65}}
            /> */}
            {/* <Image
              source={require('../../Assets/Image/mot11.jpeg')}
              style={{width: 70, height: 65}}
            /> */}

            <Text
              style={{
                color: '#000000',
                fontSize: 12,
                fontWeight: 'normal',
                fontFamily: 'Poppins-Medium',
                alignItems: 'center',
                marginTop: 8,
              }}>
              {props.userlanguage == 'English' ? val.name : val.name}{' '}
              {/* {props.userlanguage == 'English' ? val.value : val.arabicvalue}{' '} */}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    });
    return (
      <View
        key={index}
        style={{width: WIDTH, flexDirection: 'row', marginBottom: 10}}>
        {columns}
      </View>
    );
  };
```

and this is how I render data

```
 <FlatList
            data={modifyData(DataForCategory)}
            renderItem={({item, index}) => renderItem(item, index)}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          />
```

please ignore it = I am able to show ad after every 3 row . with defined data I am able to show ad after every 3 row . with defined data I am able to show ad after every 3 row . with defined data I am able to show ad after every 3 row . with defined data I am able to show ad after every 3 row . with defined data I am able to show ad after every 3 row . with defined data I am able to show ad after every 3 row . with defined data I am able to show ad after every 3 row . with defined data I am able to show ad after every 3 row . with defined data I am able to show ad after every 3 row . with defined data I am able to show ad after every 3 row . with defined data I am able to show ad after every 3 row . with defined data I am able to show ad after every 3 row . with defined data I am able to show ad after every 3 row . with defined data I am able to show ad after every 3 row . with defined data I am able to show ad after every 3 row . with defined data

Answer (score 0):

ok then the problem in state

instead of
const [DataForCategory, setDataForCategory] = useState([]);

use like this
const [DataForCategory, setDataForCategory] = useState(['']);